# "I don't know much like cooking it frozen"

Tags: prepositions, adverbs

"I don't know much like cooking it frozen"

I'm really confused because of the usage of 'much' and 'like'.

Are they both adverbs? or 'much' is 'pronoun' and 'like' is 'preposition'?

Comment: This is missing words -- no wonder you're confused. Most likely it should have been "I don't know *how* much *I* like cooking it frozen."

Comment: Or a word was added, e.g., from "“I don't much like cooking it frozen.”

Comment: This is a very confusing sentence.  Where did you find it?

Comment: Horrible sentence.  But it may be missing punctuation (like an em-dash).  "I don't know much---like cooking it frozen."  May make sense, depending on the context.

Comment: The sentence from "Lamb to the slaughter" by Roald Dahl

Answer (score 2):

The context is this, from "Lamb to the Slaughter" by Roald Dahl:

(A woman is buying vegetables at a store.)

> “Then how about meat, Mrs. Maloney?” 
> “No, I’ve got meat, thanks.  I got a nice leg of lamb from the freezer.” 
> “Oh.” 
> “I don’t know much like cooking it frozen, Sam, but I’m taking a chance on it this time.  You think it’ll be all right?”

In this context, it clearly means something like "I don't know much **about** cooking it frozen."  I would say that *much* is a pronoun and *like* is a preposition, because "I don't know much" can stand alone as a clause, and "like/about X" describes something specific about the clause.

We should note that Roald Dahl was born in Wales in 1916, and the usage of *like* here may be a regional or dated one; as a US English speaker I would not use *like* this way and would use *about* instead.

Comment: Young people in the UK are prone to insert _like_  almost anywhere for emphasis but given the author that seems unlikely here. Mrs Maloney may have started off with one construction and altered course mid-sentence of course but then we might have expected an ellipsis or other punctuation to indicate that. "I don't know much ... like cooking it frozen"

Comment: It could also be: I don't much like cooking it frozen. The editors must have been asleep at the wheel.